# Methods of Analysis: Sequence and Convergence

Tags: education, supremum-and-infimum

$A,B ⊂ R$ are non-empty bounded sets, with $α=\sup(A), B=\sup(B)$.
$Z ∈ R$ Prove that $Z + A = \{Z + x : x ∈ A\}$ is bounded and $\sup(Z + A)= Z + α$.

So far in my proof I have: $∀ x ∈ A. x ≤ α, Z + x ≤ Z + α$. Since $α = \sup(A)$ and $x ∈ A$, $x$ is bounded.

I need help finishing and adding more to the proof

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please use Mathjax. Tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

It seems right. It has to be clear that $Z + A$ fixes according to your definition $x \in A$. It is clear that $\forall y \in Z, $ $y + x \leq y + \sup(A) = y + \alpha $. Since $y$ is arbitrary in $Z$, this means $Z + A \leq Z + \alpha$. The remaining part would be proving that this is the supreme.  If it weren't like that, having fixed a certain $z \in Z$, the smallest upper bound for $z + A$ would not be $z + \alpha$, but for example $z + \beta$. This would mean that $\beta $ would be a smaller upper bound for $A$, which means $\alpha \neq \sup(A)$, which is absurd according to the initial asumption.